# How to extend object child without rewriting it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json object containing information about a person, and I want to update the data using `jQuery` extend function, the problem is that the child gets rewritten.

example:

```js
var dadThen = {
  name: "Adam",
  age: 35,
  child:{
    name: "Ben",
    age: 10
  }
}

// dad now
var dadNow = {
  age: 36,
  child: {
    age: 11
  }
}

var newData = $.extend({}, dadThen, dadNow);
// The child name gets removed
// newData.child.name is undefined
```

How to fix this?

Comment: nitpick: You dont have a "JSON object" you have a javascript object. JSON would be a string, and would have quotes round the keys.

Comment: change your `{}` to `true` like this `var newData = $.extend(true, dadThen, dadNow);` because true tells jquery to do deep copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Isnt it like this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN)

`var newData = $.extend(true, {}, dadThen, dadNow);`

first parameter is a flag whether to deep clone the object.